# tkinter canvas not updating color

Tags: python, tkinter

I draw an oval into a canvas which works perfect also it show color red and the loops runs fine too cause I can see the print. Its supposed to change the color ever 1000ms. But its not changing the color?

```
def draw_light(self):
        w = tk.Canvas(self.frame_Light)
        w.pack()
        w.create_oval(10, 10, 30, 30, fill="yellow", tags="light")

        if self.light_on:
            w.itemconfig("light", fill="blue")
            self.light_on = False
            print "on"
        else:
            w.itemconfig("light", fill="red")
            self.light_on = True
            print "of"

        self.app.after(1000, self.draw_light)
```

***UPDATE***
changed the code to your suggestions still generates only the red canvas thats it

```
def draw_light(self):
    self.ligth_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame_Light)
    self.ligth_canvas.pack()
    self.ligth_canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 30, 30, fill="yellow", tags="light")

    self.app.after(0, self.change_light)

def change_light(self):
    i = self.ligth_canvas.find_withtag("light")

    if self.light_on:
        self.ligth_canvas.itemconfig(i, fill="blue")
        self.light_on = False
        print "on"
    else:
        self.ligth_canvas.itemconfig(i, fill="red")
        self.light_on = True
        print "of"

    self.app.after(5000, self.change_light)
```

Comment: Do you realize that every second you are creating a brand new canvas without deleting the previous one(s)? Is that intentional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are creating the canvas on every iteration, and packing it below all of the other canvases. When you say the object color isn't changing, that's because you are observing the first canvas you created; the color is changing for the most recently created canvas but it is off screen.

Change your code to create a single canvas and your code will otherwise work just fine. For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.frame_Light = tk.Frame(self, background="bisque")
        self.frame_Light.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.light_on = True
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame_Light)
        self.canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 30, 30, fill="yellow", tags="light")
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.draw_light()

    def draw_light(self):

        if self.light_on:
            self.canvas.itemconfig("light", fill="blue")
            self.light_on = False
            print "on"
        else:
            self.canvas.itemconfig("light", fill="red")
            self.light_on = True
            print "of"

        self.after(1000, self.draw_light)

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: but thats nearly the same sa my update :-/ the canvas is only drawn once draw_light is called once and then only change_light is called over and over again. but thanks anyway!

Comment: I wanted to explain why your original code didn't work, which the accepted answer (at the time I wrote my answer) didn't do. I try to include a working example in most of my answers so that they are as useful as possible.

Comment: This worked superbly except when object was an arc in which case `self.canvas.itemconfig("light", fill="blue")` needs to be `self.canvas.itemconfig("light", fill="blue", outline='blue")`. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

You are using [**itemconfig**](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method) incorrectly; it takes an item, not a tag.

Try [**find_withtag**](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_withtag-method) to get all items tagged "light", then use `itemconfig` on that.

You should also pay attention to what Bryan Oakley said. Right now you're creating a new canvas and oval every time. Better place the first three lines of this method elsewhere where they aren't repeated.

Comment: @Junuxx: What you say is false - itemconfig absolutely can take a tag.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I stand corrected; itemconfig expects an *item specifier*, which can be an item handle, tag, tk.ALL or tk.CURRENT.