# Tkinter Canvas will not update color change via itemconfig

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am working on a project which deals with a kind of a map which has some lines as paths. These paths can have two states, active and inactive with different colors. There is a method which should change the fill-color.
I can't figure out why my canvas lines won't update. Here's my simplified code:

```
import Tkinter

inactive = "#385c61"
active = "#7dd5cd"

map = Tkinter.Canvas()

class GuiPart(object):

    def __init__(self, master):
        #some code

    def initGui(self, master):
        map = Tkinter.Canvas(left, width=660, height=600, bg="#35424b", bd="0", highlightthickness="0")
        map.pack()
        global inactive, active
        pathA = map.create_line(135, c, 135, e, fill=inactive, width=w)

    def setActivePath(self):
        global active, inactive
        map.itemconfig(pathA, fill=active)
        map.update_idletasks()
        map.update()

root = Tkinter.Tk()
gui = GuiPart(root)
gui.initGui(root)

gui.setActivePath()

root.mainloop()
```

If I change the color with `itemconfig` inside `initGui` it works like it should, but later I have to call `setActivePath` from another class, so it has to be a own method.
(I know I call `map = Tkinter.Canvas(...)` twice, but otherwise I get an error, have to fix that too)

Any ideas?

Comment: Hm, now after i changed the code with the help of R. Murray, i dont get an error if i delete the first call of the canvas. But the main problem, that the color does not change is still there...

Comment: @forever_engineer I'm working on it now.

Comment: Try clear `class type` and `namespace` methods. You want to access `loop` inside elements (can be call internaly(mouse event, button, etc))!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `map` and `pathA` attributes of the class so that `setActivePath` can reference it. This is why you were getting the error where you had to create two canvases.

```
import Tkinter

inactive = "#385c61"
active = "#7dd5cd"

class GuiPart(object):

    def __init__(self, master):       
        #some code

    def initGui(self, master):                     
        self.map = Tkinter.Canvas(left, width=660, height=600, bg="#35424b", bd="0", highlightthickness="0")
        self.map.pack()    
        global inactive, active
        self.pathA = map.create_line(135, c, 135, e, fill=inactive, width=w)

    def setActivePath(self):
        global active, inactive
        self.map.itemconfig(self.pathA, fill=active)
        self.map.update_idletasks()
        self.map.update()

root = Tkinter.Tk()
gui = GuiPart(root)            
gui.initGui(root)

gui.setActivePath()

root.mainloop()
```

Everything else looks OK to me, though you are saying that this has not resolved your issue. As far as I can see, `self.map.itemconfig(self.pathA, fill=active)` is correct use of this method (see [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683395/tkinter-canvas-not-updating-color)) so it is possible that your problem is outside of the code you have posted. I can't test the code properly as you have not included the code in the `__init__` method and because on the computer I am using at sixth form only Python 3.4.1 is installed. Please edit your question to include the code in the `__init__` method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response! But this doesnt seem to work... The color of the line does not update.

Comment: @forever_engineer Please read the edited answer and edit your question as requested.